# Bash issues with output

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
/bin/sh
echo  "Compare Ran" $(date) >> /var/log/ran.log
if cmp -s "/var/log/ip.log" "/etc/wanip.log"
then
   echo "Wan Check Ran" | /var/log/ran.log
else
   echo "WARNING IP CHANGE" | sendmail *********@email.****.net
fi
```

If the 2 files don't match the script works great but if the 2 files match I get the following output:

```
/var/log/ran.log: 1: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 2: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 3: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 4: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 5: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 6: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 7: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 8: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 9: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 10: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 11: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 12: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 13: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 14: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 15: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 16: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 17: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 18: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 19: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 20: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 21: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 22: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 23: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 24: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 25: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 26: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 27: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 28: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 29: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 30: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 31: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 32: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 33: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 34: /var/log/ran.log: Thu: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 35: /var/log/ran.log: Compare: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 36: /var/log/ran.log: Compare: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 37: /var/log/ran.log: wanip.sh: not found
/var/log/ran.log: 38: /var/log/ran.log: Compare: not found
```

I can not for the life of me figure out why the script seems to be "reading" the ran.log file if the 2 files are the same.

Any Ideas?

Comment: How did that PIPE get in there? lol that was it, Thanks!

Comment: You need to #! before /bin/sh or it will use whatever is your current shell

Comment: yeah the "sha bang" did not play well with the code window so I left it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code is trying to execute '/var/log/ran.log' as a script

```
echo "Wan Check Ran" | /var/log/ran.log
```

While I believe that you want to add the string "Wan Check Ran" to the log. Therefore you should

```
echo "Wan Check Ran" >> /var/log/ran.log
```